# How can I modify the css of Firefox's about:profiles page? And can this be done with an extension? I find it a bit hard to use with many profiles

Tags: css, firefox, browser, firefox-addon

I like the profile switcher in Chrome, it's neat and quick to use. Firefox's about:profile page feels clunky to me by comparison. There is a Firefox profile switcher extension but it requires installing a binary. I could get away with just modifying the CSS of the about:profile page. I'm also wondering if this can be done in an extension?

I tried following the Mozilla [Your first extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension) guide, but found I couldn't 'match' the about:profile page.

Comment: Friendly reminder: If an answer was helpful to you, please accept/upvote it. Otherwise, you can comment to clarify your needs or request additional info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extensions can't modify pages with `about:` URLs, but you can add your own CSS to them with a userContent.css file. First, create it in much the same way you'd [create a userChrome.css file](https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html), except instead name it userContent.css. Then create this @-rule inside:

```css
@-moz-document url("about:profiles") {

}
```

Any CSS inside that rule will be applied exclusively to `about:profiles` (and anything outside will be applied to all pages in all tabs). The Inspector and Style Editor of the Web Developer Tools will work as you'd expect. userchrome.org also has [a list of community sites](https://www.userchrome.org/find-user-style-recipes.html) where you can get help and share your work.